# How to run delayed_job of a specific queue in test envoirnment?

Tags: delayed-job

I am trying to run specific delayed_jobs with the following script but its not working :

```
  options[:queues] ||= [BULK_EMAIL_DJ_QUEUE]
  Delayed::Worker.new(options).work_off
```

I have seen other solutions to run specifix delayed_jobs by running commands:

```
Delayed::Worker.new.run(Delayed::Job.last)
```

But i want to run all delayed jobs of a specific queue, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
Delayed::Worker.new(queues: ['my_queue']).work_off
```

works for me with Rails 4.2, Delayed Job 4.1 and RSpec 3.5